# What would the big O notation be for this particular code, It seems that a for loop with a worse time notation is nested in one thats O(1)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

As stated previously, in the attached photo, the for loop with a bigger time complexity is nested in one that is with O(1), so what is the overall time complexity? and why?

```
void function(int n) {
    int i;
    int x = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
        for (j=0; j<n/2; j++)
            x--;
}
```

Comment: I presume that this is your homework? Having us solve this, doesn't teach you anything. Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. As to homework questions: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: You should change this question to use text for the code not a screen shot

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I shall keep them in mind. I assure you your presumption is wrong Adrian, I'm actually in the process of revision for exams and the materials i was provided with were not rigorous enough and hence prompted me to ask for further clarification. But I do understand your concern regarding homework questions and your reaction given that my question does indeed look like a homework question. Regardless, thanks again for your knowledge, Adriaan and jwezorek!

Answer (score 1):

It’s O(n).

The inner loop is all that matters there since the outer loop runs a constant number of times. The outer loop’s contribution is just a constant factor which you ignore when figuring out Big-O.

Comment: Right, so my intuition is as follows, this is because the time complexity of both loops would be 1 x N right? so either way its O(N)? or is that understanding wrong?

Comment: well any time you have a nested loop, it means to multiply their individual time complexities e.g. if you have a loop that is O(log n) nested in a loop that is O(n) the time complexity of the whole thing will be O(n log n) because the log n loop will run about n times. in this case you have an O(n) loop that will run about O(1) times so multiplying just yields O(n) .